# vim run make and open quickfix without additional <CR>

Tags: vim, ide

In my .vimrc I have:

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* nested lwindow
set makeprg=ninja-build\ -C\ build
map <f9> :make<CR>
```

So when I press F9 build process is started, and then, depending if there are compilation errors, one of the following happens:

**If there are errors, I see**

```
...
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

message in end of the build output. I press 'enter', go back to vim and quickfix window is opened with errors.

**If there are no errors,** I see an empty buffer with the following message:

```
(1 of 3): ninja: Entering directory `build'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And again, I have to press 'enter', go back to vim. (no quickfix window opens, which is nice).

**The desired behavior** - in case of errors go back to vim immediately( without waiting for me to press 'enter') and open quickfix. If there are no errors - go back to vim immediately without showing an empty buffer, and without pressing 'enter'. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help :silent` should fix both issues:

```
nnoremap <f9> :silent make<CR>
```

Also… `nested` is probably not necessary.